# how to make bold matched text in autocomplete jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I need your help, I am using Autocomplete-Jquery. I need to bold text in dropdown list of autocomplete suggestions. How I can do ? Please help me in this regard. thanks.

this is my code:

```
   $(function () {
        $("#age").autocomplete({
            source: '{% url 'autocomplete' %}',
            appendTo: "#appendToHere",
            select: function(event, ui) {
                selectedItem = ui.item.value;
                document.getElementById("age").value = selectedItem;

                $("#searchBtn").click();
            },
        });
    });
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The following Demo may assist: https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data It is also best to provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example Currently, you do have a Minimal example yet it cannot be replicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following example.

```js
$(function() {
  var availableTags = [
    "ActionScript",
    "AppleScript",
    "Asp",
    "BASIC",
    "C",
    "C++",
    "Clojure",
    "COBOL",
    "ColdFusion",
    "Erlang",
    "Fortran",
    "Groovy",
    "Haskell",
    "Java",
    "JavaScript",
    "Lisp",
    "Perl",
    "PHP",
    "Python",
    "Ruby",
    "Scala",
    "Scheme"
  ];

  function boldStr(needle, haystack) {
    var regex = new RegExp(needle, 'i');
    return haystack.replace(regex, "<span class='bold'>" + needle + "</span>");
  }

  $("#tags").autocomplete({
    source: availableTags
  }).autocomplete("instance")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
    return $("<li>")
      .append("<div>" + boldStr($("#tags").val(), item.label) + "</div>")
      .appendTo(ul);
  };;
});
```

```css
.bold {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
  <input id="tags">
</div>
```

You can use Replace to replace a portion of a String. See More: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

You can use the Extension Points to modify the items in the list. See More: https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#method-_renderItem

Comment: Thank you so much Sir, I have been searching for last days, you are awesome. god bless you. cheers!